# How to specify where CMake is installed in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, cmake, installation

I have downloaded the `cmake-3.11.3-Linux-x86_64.sh` file. Then I executed it and it created a folder that has a `bin` file there is `cmake` on it. I tried to edit `/etc/environment` like this:

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/m/FILES/CMake/cmake-3.11.3-Linux-x86_64/bin"
```

But when I try this command:

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local ..
```

I get this message:

> The program 'cmake' is currently not installed. You can install it by
>   typing: sudo apt install cmake

Which part of what I did, is wrong and how can I fix that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you downloaded the script from [CMake's Download Page](https://cmake.org/download/). The documentation how to use it is admittedly a little sparse.

In short, call (installation path for CMake here is `/usr/local`):

```
# sudo cmake-3.11.3-Linux-x86_64.sh --skip-license --exclude-subdir --prefix=/usr/local
```

*Note*: You need to uninstall any package manager installed CMake packages first

```
# sudo apt remove cmake
# sudo apt purge --auto-remove cmake
```

**Options**

The script has the following options:

```
# cmake-3.11.3-Linux-x86_64.sh --help
Usage: cmake-3.11.3-Linux-x86_64.sh [options]
Options: [defaults in brackets after descriptions]
  --help            print this message
  --version         print cmake installer version
  --prefix=dir      directory in which to install
  --include-subdir  include the cmake-3.11.3-Linux-x86_64 subdirectory
  --exclude-subdir  exclude the cmake-3.11.3-Linux-x86_64 subdirectory
  --skip-license    accept license
```

The one you are searching for is `--prefix=dir`. Otherwise it will just use the current directory to extract the installation files.

**Test Output on Ubuntu**

```
# cmake-3.11.3-Linux-x86_64.sh --skip-license --exclude-subdir --prefix=/usr/local
CMake Installer Version: 3.11.3, Copyright (c) Kitware
This is a self-extracting archive.
The archive will be extracted to: /usr/local

Using target directory: /usr/local
Extracting, please wait...

Unpacking finished successfully

# cmake --version
cmake version 3.11.3

CMake suite maintained and supported by Kitware (kitware.com/cmake).
```

**Reference / Alternative**

- [Ask Ubuntu: How do I install the latest version of cmake from the command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/355565/how-do-i-install-the-latest-version-of-cmake-from-the-command-line)

Comment: I had to use # sudo bash cmake... instead of # sudo cmake... 
which I figured out only after some pattern matching. Is this a typo in the answer or am I simply crazy?

Answer (score 2):

Rather than installing **CMake** mannually,
Please let **apt** take care of it.

Just rollback whatever changes you've done.
Simply type `sudo apt install cmake` on your terminal.

and you're ready to use CMake since **apt** takes care of all dependencies installations and environment variable  settings.

I hope, this will help.

Comment: Thank you, But what version of CMake it will install?

Comment: It depends on repository.
Most probably, the latest one.  
If you want to check just run `cmake --version`.

Comment: Do you know the command that I can search the Repo to find which version of it will be installed, before I do install!

Comment: `$apt-cache madison cmake
`  or
`$apt-cache policy cmake`  

Best Luck!

Comment: The result is CMake 3.5.1 and 6 version before than what I wanted to install. But as you suggested I will install it and hope it works well.

Comment: Alright :)  
https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/debian-ubuntu-linux-apt-get-aptitude-show-package-version-command/  
_For further reading._

Answer (score 0):

These are the following steps you need to do to upgrade your cmake to the latest version or download cmake if you don't have it:

**Case 1: I have already have/downloaded cmake on my machine, but I want to upgrade it.**

1. If you already have/downloaded cmake before on your machine, then you need to remove it first:

```bash
sudo apt remove cmake
sudo apt purge --auto-remove cmake
```

**Case 2: I never have cmake on my machine, but I want download it and I want the latest version.**

1. Just proceed to step 2.

---

2. Download the binary distribution from [cmake website](https://cmake.org/download/), for example: `cmake-3.25.1-linux-x86_64.sh`
3. Inside the directory where you have installed the binary distribution from step 2, run the command below (assume I have renamed the downloaded file to `cmake.sh` for simplicity):

```bash
sudo sh cmake.sh --prefix=/usr/local/ --exclude-subdir
```

4. Check you have it installed by running:

```bash
cmake --version
```

The steps above won't require you to fix paths and all that, and they're simple steps you can do everytime you want to download the latest version of cmake.

Source:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_yFPO1ofyF0&list=PLK6MXr8gasrGmIiSuVQXpfFuE1uPT615s