# Can't install cmake Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: opencv, ubuntu, cmake, ubuntu-16.04, libjson

Try to install openCV lib and one of the first steps is install cmake, but when I

```
sudo apt-get install cmake
```

I recieve

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 cmake : Depends: libjsoncpp0 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I'd installed `build-essential, libjsoncpp-dev, pkg-config...` etc

Where is error?

Comment: The package name is `libjsoncpp0` not `libjsoncpp`. Maybe that helps further.

Comment: Yes, but then I `sudo apt install libjsoncpp0` i receive `Package libjsoncpp0 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libjsoncpp0' has no installation candidate
`

Comment: What version of cmake are you trying to install? `libjsoncpp0` is not supported anymore since Ubuntu 14.04. The only repo I am aware of is https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/trusty/universe/base/libjsoncpp0 . But I doubt cmake references this package.

Comment: You link help's thank you, by default with `..install cmake` i recieve 3.5.2 version

Comment: Related [How to specify where CMake is installed in Ubuntu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50656556/how-to-specify-where-cmake-is-installed-in-ubuntu) It shows how to install the latest version.